# Progressbar.js animation choppy rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I'm using progressbar.js to render progress circles on [this](http://rondreizen.ravenwebdesign.nl/reisorganisatie-single.php). It works fine except for in IE, where it seems to render extremely choppy. Would anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not support animating SVG properties with CSS transitions.

Comment: But why do all these examples work in IE than? http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/